# Android - Buttons take 2-3 seconds to be pressed

Tags: java, android, button

The activity loads flawlessly, and the countDownTimer on the activity has no issues, however the 4 buttons I have take 2-3 seconds to become depressed and complete the assigned task.

Some worthy notes maybe:

- The previous activity has no problems.
- There are only 4 buttons, 4 small imageViews, and 2 textViews.
- Pressing on the buttons (some of which do nothing) causes the countDownTimer to freeze, but it runs fine in the background and catches up if you know what I mean.

I can post my code if it helps..

Thanks in advance I'm really new to this

.

Here is my code:

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private boolean isPaused=false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomQuestion = random.nextInt(3);//number is the number of questions and should probably not be hard coded

    Resources res = getResources();

//Timer initiation
    final TextView timerTextView = findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timerTextView.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            if(isPaused) {
                //transfer timer info to next Activity
                cancel();
                finish();
            }
        }
        public void onFinish() {
           timerTextView.setText("Done!");
           //start gameOverActivity
        }
    }.start();

//declare question array and answer array
    TypedArray answerResources = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.answers);
    int resId = answerResources.getResourceId(randomQuestion, -1);//gets the ID of the nth string array
    answerResources.recycle();//free
    //if (resId < 0) {QUESTION DOES NOT EXIST.  CHECK strings.xml OR RNG}
    String [] questionAnswers = res.getStringArray(resId);
    String[] questions = res.getStringArray(R.array.question_array);

//declare buttons and textView
    TextView questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);
    Button firstAnswerBtn = findViewById(R.id.firstAnswerBtn);
    Button secondAnswerBtn = findViewById(R.id.secondAnswerBtn);
    Button thirdAnswerBtn = findViewById(R.id.thirdAnswerBtn);
    Button fourthAnswerBtn = findViewById(R.id.fourthAnswerBtn);
    Button[] answerButtons = {firstAnswerBtn,secondAnswerBtn,thirdAnswerBtn,fourthAnswerBtn};

//shuffle the four answers:
    int correctIndex=0;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        int randomShuffle = random.nextInt(4);
        if(i==correctIndex){//keep track of the correct answer (which always starts at 0)
            correctIndex=randomShuffle;
        }
        else if(randomShuffle==correctIndex){
            correctIndex=i;
        }
        String hold=questionAnswers[i];//quick lil swapperoo
        questionAnswers[i]=questionAnswers[randomShuffle];
        questionAnswers[randomShuffle]=hold;
    }

//set1  the question and the buttons to the randomQuestion
    questionTextView.setText(questions[randomQuestion]);
    answerButtons[0].setText(questionAnswers[0]);
    answerButtons[1].setText(questionAnswers[1]);
    answerButtons[2].setText(questionAnswers[2]);
    answerButtons[3].setText(questionAnswers[3]);


    answerButtons[correctIndex].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent playIntent = new Intent(PlayActivity.this, PlayActivity.class);
            startActivity(playIntent);
            isPaused=true;
            finish();
        }
    });

}

public void onBackPressed() {
    backButtonOverride();
}

public void backButtonOverride(){
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PlayActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("!");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Return to Main Menu?");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent start = new Intent(PlayActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(start);
                    finish();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of following lines in your onClick:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent playIntent = new Intent(PlayActivity.this, PlayActivity.class);
    startActivity(playIntent);
    isPaused=true;
    finish();
}
```

You are starting and destroying same activity. Which can takes a while. It's not a good idea to do in this way.

Simply call a method on same Activity to update the necessary views rather than creating and destroying same activity.

Comment: So, when I commented out the lines starting a new activity, the buttons still take 2-3 seconds to be pressed (even though they don't do anything I still see the extremely slow animation).  I can't seem to pin point what's causing it.  Could someone maybe explain to me exactly how onCreate works??

Comment: No I am not.  MotoG3 if it matters

Comment: @microflakes If you are not doing anything on your button, how do know its taking long time? Also ensure you clean and build the app, some time instant run doesn't take changes into consideration

Comment: I can see the button animation.  It takes a very long time for the button to become depressed.  Also, cleaning and re-building the app did not change anything.  I am currently trying older versions to see where I went wrong.

Comment: It seems to be a hardware issue.  I tried on a tablet and it works fine.  I will close the issue, however do you have any idea as to why this might happen?  It wasn't happening before on this device.  I have uninstalled, cleared cache etc...

Comment: I found some pf the moto devices are some times slow to respond. Epescially the ones with lower version of Android.